# how to solve django.db.utils.NotSupportedError in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, mariadb

I got an error while running the project in Django. the thing is that unfortunately i upgraded my pip , MySQL client and Django versions

this is the error while running python manage.py run server

```
in check_database_version_supported
raise NotSupportedError(
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MariaDB 10.3 or later is required (found 10.1.19).
```

Comment: actually am stuck this area badly. I am using MySQL for database dint want to convert it to MariaDB

Comment: You have a MariaDB-10.1.19 client installed to  MySQL server, and your application found that 10.1.19. As in the error you need to have MariaDB 10.3 or later. You coluld try upgrading MariaDB

Comment: how can i solve this issue as soon as possible with my mysql database?

Comment: By updating MariaDB

Comment: can you suggest the stept to upgrade mariadb?

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UfTyzbszDQ] thank you .i resolved this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a MariaDB-10.1.19 client installed to MySQL server, and your application found that 10.1.19. As in the error you need to have MariaDB 10.3 or later. You can upgrade MariaDB as

- First stop the xampp server completely.
- Then go to [MariaDB download page](https://mariadb.org/download/) and download the zip file of latest stable version
- extract the file, and rename the folder from `mariadb-10.x.x` to `mysql`
- Then in your `C:` drive go to `xampp` directory and change the mysql folder name to `mysql_old`
- Then copy the extracted folder to `xampp` directory.
- Then go to `mysql_old` directory and copy `backups` folder, `scripts` folder, `mysqlinstallservice` file, `mysqluninstallservice` file and paste to `mysql` folder.
- Then go to `bin` folder in `mysql_old` and copy `my` file to `bin` folder in `mysql` folder.
- Then edit `my` file in mysql and add `skip-grant-tables` in line before `#skip-federated`, also delete this line `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M`, then save the file.
- Then in `bin` folder open `mysql_upgrade` and run it.
- After ran succesfully, rename `data` folder as `data_new` in `mysql` folder, then copy `data` folder from `mysql_old` folder to `mysql` folder.
- Now run `xampp` control panel and start `apache` server and `mysql`.

Now MariaDB is updated and issue will be solved.